# CSS files not working in brave browser but works fine with chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hosting, brave

[this is how it looks in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnjQ6.jpg)

and [this is how it looks on brave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9XaC.jpg)

I am using the current version of brave browser and to note I have developed this website using brave browser and it worked fine and seems like brave does support all my css animations
but when I hosted my project this gone bad I couldn't figure out what was wrong.is this because of hosting service if so why does it works with chrome.
I have also tried with opera and firefox and even there everything works

Comment: Can you try turning off hardware acceleration under brave://settings?